# Eloquent Javascript (findInRemoteStorage) .then executing a function, but choosing not to return promise that resolves to its return value

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

This is from Eloquent JavaScript's [Chapter 11 - Asynchronous Programming](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html) and all related code can be found in [crow-tech.js](https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/crow-tech.js) and [chapter/11_async.js](https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/chapter/11_async.js)

Can someone tell me what that comma after next() is doing? I don't mean what the comma operator does, but why structure it that way? The hope would be that one of these recursive calls to next() finally produces a valid 'value' - why is 'next(),next' necessary? So it executes next() again, but returns... just the 'next' function object - instead of a promise that resolves to the return value of next()(which sounds like what is actually needed?). Why? WHY? I am so confused.

I know it's hard to understand what's going on without taking a bunch of time, so if anyone has a suggestion of a a good way to answer questions about a specific book, let me know.

```
.then(value => value != null ? value : next(),
      next);
```

from:

```
function findInRemoteStorage(nest, name) {
  let sources = network(nest).filter(n => n != nest.name);
  function next() {
    if (sources.length == 0) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error("Not found"));
    } else {
      let source = sources[Math.floor(Math.random() *
        sources.length)];
      sources = sources.filter(n => n != source);
      return routeRequest(nest, source, "storage", name)
        .then(value => value != null ? value : next(),
          next);
    }
  }
  return next();
}
```

Comment: This looks more like the second argument to `.then()` than the comma-operator. The second argument to `.then()` is a function, which gets invoked when the Promise rejects. So `next` is a function that gets executed if the Promise rejects, and `value => value != null ? value : next()` is the function that executes if the Promise resolves

Comment: @NickParsons Mamma frickin mia I was waaaay off thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone tell me what that comma after next() is doing?

The line you're asking about:

```
.then(value => value != null ? value : next(), next);
```

is passing two values to `.then()` as in `.then(resolveFn, rejectFn)`.  So, the comma is just separating two arguments to `.then()`.  The first argument is:

```
value != null ? value : next()
```

And, the second argument (separated with the comma) is:

```
next()
```

It is equivalent to this more verbose (and annotated with comments) way of expressing the code:

```
.then(value => {
   if (value != null) {
       // got a value, we're done
       return value;
   } else {
        // didn't get a value, try again with a different sources value
        return next();
   }
}, err => {
   // got a promise reject error, try again with a different sources value
   return next(err);
});
```

Which appears to basically just keep calling `next()` until it gets a resolved value which is probably safe here because each time it tries again, it selects a random value from the sources array and then removes that value that was selected from the sources array for the next try.  Eventually, all values will be removed from the sources array and then it will reject or one of them will succeed and it will be done.